# Obtener datos por URL en rest api yii2

Tags: yii

Actualmente obtengo datos de mi servicio de la siguiente forma:

http://localhost/users?fields=nombre

Y el servicio me muestra todos los usuarios pero unicamente sus nopmbres como especifico en la ruta.

Ahora quisiera que me mostrara un dato en especifico. ej.:

http://localhost/users?fields=nombre=Jorge  y me mostrara solo el nombre de "jorge"

Mi servicio lo levanto de la siguiente manera El controlador:

class AmigosController extends ActiveController
{
   public $modelClass = 'backend\models\Amigos';
}
...

El modelo:

class Amigos extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'amigos';
    }

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['idUsuarioAmigo', 'idUsuarioAgregadoAmigo', 'fechaAltaAmigo', 'estatusAmigo'], 'required'],
        [['idUsuarioAmigo', 'idUsuarioAgregadoAmigo'], 'integer'],
        [['fechaAltaAmigo'], 'safe'],
        [['estatusAmigo'], 'string', 'max' => 20],
        [['idUsuarioAgregadoAmigo'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Usuarios::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['idUsuarioAgregadoAmigo' => 'idUsuario']],
        [['idUsuarioAmigo'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Usuarios::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['idUsuarioAmigo' => 'idUsuario']],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'idAmigo' => Yii::t('app', 'Id Amigo'),
        'idUsuarioAmigo' => Yii::t('app', 'Id Usuario Amigo'),
        'idUsuarioAgregadoAmigo' => Yii::t('app', 'Id Usuario Agregado Amigo'),
        'fechaAltaAmigo' => Yii::t('app', 'Fecha Alta Amigo'),
        'estatusAmigo' => Yii::t('app', 'Estatus Amigo'),
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente lo que quieres hacer es un "search"

http://localhost/users?fields=nombre&nombre=jorge

y en el index de AmigosController puedes escribir la logica. Recuerda que el nombre lo obtienes con:

```
Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('nombre')
```

en este caso